# Does 'submit()' method impede 'submit' event listener to be executed?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I feel like I'm asking "what's 2+2 ?" but I'm facing an issue I don't understand... Here is the code, easy to understand:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="send()">
<form id="form">
  <input name="name">
</form>

<script>
  const form = document.getElementById("form");
  function send() {
    form.submit();
  }
  form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
    // This code never gets executed,
    // the default behavior still works.
    // (note that my console preserves logs,
    // so it should be visible even though the page is being refreshed.)
    console.log("preventing default behavior");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

Could someone help me on that one ? It should be so easy but for some reason the code doesn't want to be nice with me tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the (somewhat unintuitive) expected behavior. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) for `HTMLFormElement.submit()`:

> This method is similar, but not identical to, activating a form's submit . When invoking this method directly, however:
>
> - **No submit event is raised. In particular, the form's onsubmit event handler is not run.**
> - Constraint validation is not triggered.
>
> The [`HTMLFormElement.requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) method is identical to activating a form's submit  and does not have these differences.

So, you can use `form.requestSubmit` instead of `form.submit`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const form = document.getElementById("form");
  function send() {
    form.submit();
  }
  form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
    // This code never gets executed,
    // the default behavior still works.
    // (note that my console preserves logs,
    // so it should be visible even though the page is being refreshed.)
    
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("preventing default behavior");
    send();
  });
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input name="name">
  <button type="submit" >submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It is a solution but i wanted the button outside the form

Comment: what difference does it make?

Comment: It's just that i didn't want to modify my HTML structure